# Using save() on a variable name and value connected through assign() in R

Tags: r, save, assign

I'm making a R function in which I use `assign(variable_name,some_data_frame)` to connect the value of `variable_name`, which has a value `some_string` (found inside the function),  to `some_data_frame`.  This gives me the ability to call the name with `>variable_name` and the data frame by `>get(variable_name)`.

What I'm actually trying to do is making the variable:

```
some_string <- some_data_frame
```

... and then save it.
I thought I could do this by `calling save()` like this :

```
save(get(variable_name),file = paste(c(variable_name,'.Rda'),collapse=""))
```

Turns out, `save()` does not allow `get()` ito be inside the function.  Any tips/better ways to do this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need the step with `assign()` if you then save it? can you just write `save(some_data_frame), file = paste0(some_string, ".Rda")` ?

Comment: yes, since I want it to be save with the correct variable name (not just the file name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution (in a thread I unfortunately overlooked previously)
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/289404.html
Thus : 
do.call(save, list(variable_name, file=paste(variable_name, "rda", sep = ".")))

@PiotrZieliński   @LarsArneJordanger

Comment: nice! exactly what I needed. Its one of those R quirks thats tough to wrap your head around.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure should solve your problem.

```
variable_name <- "some_string"
some_data_frame <- data.frame()


assign(x = variable_name,
       value = some_data_frame)


save_quote <- bquote(
    save(.(as.name(variable_name)),
         file = paste0(c(.(variable_name)),
                       ".Rda")))

save_quote
save(some_string, file = paste0(c("some_string"), ".Rda"))

eval(save_quote)
```

The idea is that the `bquote` + `.()` construction creates the call
you need, and then you only need to evaluate that call.

Comment: I don't see how this helps, but perhaps you're on to something.  This only calls the string value of variable_name - and not the data.frame.  I also tried replacing as.name() with get(), which kind of worked, but gave me an error  (didn't say which)

Comment: The error was just "error" and some list representing my data.frame